# hive: to_map function not working

Tags: hive, udf

I have below data into the hive table;

```
select pid, year, catches  from fielding_s where  pid = 'zobribe01' group by id;

zobribe01       2006    [{"p1":52,"p2":50,"p3":1322,"p4":86}]  
zobribe01       2007    [{"p1":30,"p2":26,"p3":674,"p4":37}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":8,"p2":4,"p3":123,"p4":11}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":1,"p2":0,"p3":14,"p4":0}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":5,"p2":3,"p3":81,"p4":8}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":14,"p2":8,"p3":238,"p4":21}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":19,"p2":12,"p3":340,"p4":29}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":2,"p2":1,"p3":21,"p4":0}]  
zobribe01       2008    [{"p1":35,"p2":33,"p3":880,"p4":51}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":3,"p2":2,"p3":39,"p4":6}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":91,"p2":81,"p3":2144,"p4":143}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":1,"p2":1,"p3":17,"p4":0}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":7,"p2":5,"p3":140,"p4":15}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":1,"p2":null,"p3":null,"p4":null}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":9,"p2":2,"p3":114,"p4":8}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":70,"p2":44,"p3":1242,"p4":112}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":59,"p2":37,"p3":988,"p4":89}]  
zobribe01       2009    [{"p1":13,"p2":6,"p3":186,"p4":9}]  
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":14,"p2":9,"p3":237,"p4":77}]  
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":55,"p2":45,"p3":1113,"p4":74}]  
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":2,"p2":1,"p3":30,"p4":1}]  
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":14,"p2":9,"p3":250,"p4":22}] 
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":1,"p2":0,"p3":6,"p4":0}]  
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":110,"p2":89,"p3":2504,"p4":204}]    
zobribe01       2010    [{"p1":103,"p2":80,"p3":2248,"p4":182}]  
zobribe01       2011    [{"p1":131,"p2":118,"p3":3175,"p4":213}]  
zobribe01       2011    [{"p1":38,"p2":33,"p3":869,"p4":65}]
```

I want to merge these rows into a table using to_map function. I am running below query but it gives me below error.

```
select pid, to_map(year, catches) from fielding_s where  pid = 'zobribe01' group by pid;
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:12 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'catches'

Comment: Could you try add the `catches` to your group by ?? `select pid, to_map(year,catches) from fielding_s where  pid = 'zobribe01' group by pid, catches`;

Comment: Still same error
hive> select pid, to_map(year,catches) from fielding_s where pid = 'zobribe01' group by pid, catches;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:12 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'catches'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by` clause from you query and then try

```
select id, map(name, designation) b from snow
```